# Excel VBA Userform How to add and subtract variables?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Userform, on Page 1 of the Userform the user enters some text into a TextBox called as_1 and another TextBox called annualsaving1.

On Page 5 of the Userform I would like to add both variables up in Textbox called 'TextBox36'. 
This is the code I have been using:

```
Private Sub Page5a()
I = as_1 + annualsaving1
TextBox36.Value = I
End Sub
```

When I use this code, only the value of as_1 appears. It doesn't add 'annualsaving1'.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`as_1` and `annualsaving1` are of type `TextBox`. To add their values, you need to access their `.Value` property and convert it to type `Integer`:

```
I = CInt(as_1.value) + CInt(annualsaving1.value)
```

Be careful though: if user enters something that cannot be parsed as number, your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
Private Sub Page5a()
    TextBox36.Text = Val(as_1.Text) + Val(annualsaving1.Text)
End Sub
```